# Is there a replacement for search terms now that google search is encrypted?

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics, jetpack

I run a personal blog and use jetpack for viewing stats in addition to using google analytics.

Till sometime back i was able to see what search terms people use to find my blog, this helped me write targeted posts and hence increase traffic but since Google has made search encrypted jetpack shows search terms as unsupported search terms. I understand this is because jetpack is unable to interpret encrypted search terms.

My question is, is there an alternate way to search terms with which i can find what my audience like and hence write better blogs?

Comment: Google Analytics should tell you.

Comment: I get a good number of them as (not provided) in Google analytics.

Comment: People might be finding your site from links, or their own bookmarks, or some other means. There wouldn't be any search terms in those cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a webmaster tools account and link it to your Google Analytics Account - this will at least get you a general overview which keywords where used how often to find your site (but will not tell you which keyword led to which landing page etc.).

It is not possible to get keyword information from ssl encrypted searches, so the keywords report is by now pretty much useless (I guess that's part of Googles ongoing war against SEO companies).

Comment: So there is no way i can continue doing what i used to do, write targeted posts?